# Color Formatting of Cells based on Color Formatting of other Cells

Tags: excel, colors, formatting, conditional-statements, vba

I hope you can help. I was just wondering if the color formatting in Excel 2010 can be used to color format a cell based on the color of another cell.

I have attached a picture below of my issue. What I would like to do is if my columns %Records outstanding for submission, % Customers Stuck, % TOV's Stuck, %Outstanding. are green then the Results Column will be Green. Or if one of these columns is red then the results column is red, and so on for yellow and other combinations
Can the results column be color formatted based on the color of other columns or must I do the math and format the color that way for the results column?

Any help would be greatly appreciated 
Pic Below 
[image]

Comment: I think the quickest approach would be to put in the Result column an IF combined with OR statement for every column you desire and then based on the IF result color the column result. One other way is to make a custom vba function that will check for the .interiorColor value of the cell from the same row in every column..

Comment: @rosuandreimihai: Thank you for the feedback. I think and If statement would be easiest way. What I am trying to express is this. IF Cell O4 = "NO" then sum C4,F4,I4,L4 and color red cell red also I want IF Cell O4 = "YES" and C4 <11 and F4 is between 0 and 1 and I4 is between 0 and 1, and  I4 is between 0 and 1 then sum and color green. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You could try it like that and see what happens :)